# React dnd to push object of dropped item to component's state.

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

In my component, there are local state of paid and droppedItems.

```
constructor () {
 super();
 this.state = {
  droppedItems: [],
};
```

And I specified drop specification like below,

`drop(props, monitor) {
    const orderItem = monitor.getItem();
  },`

What I want to do is that when an `orderItem` is dropped to the target, it pushes `orderItem` to state of `droppedItems` So to do that, I made `handleDrop` function

```
handleDrop (orderItem) {
 if(!orderItem){
     this.setState(update(this.state, {
  droppedItems: orderItem ? {
    $push: [orderItem]
  } : {}
}));
}
else return false;
}
```

And call it like this

```
return connectDropTarget(
            <div className="payment_block" onDrop={this.handleDrop}>
```

In my render function, there are `const { canDrop, connectDropTarget, getItem} = this.props;`

Below is result from `console.log(this.props)`

`Object { id: 1, order: Object, channel: undefined, dispatch: routerMiddleware/</</<(), connectDropTarget: wrapHookToRecognizeElement/<(), canDrop: false, itemType: "order_item", getItem: Object`

Although it recognizes that there is a dropped item, it does not push to the state.

How can I push above `Object` of `getItem` to the component's state? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `drop` also receives your dnd decorated `component` as its third argument, so you should be able to call your `handleAdd` method.

```
drop(props, monitor, component) {
  component.handleDrop(monitor.getItem());
}
```

Also the if statement in your `handleDrop` method is checking that no `orderItem` is passed in, which means the code will never run when you want it to, I'm not familiar with the what your `update` function does (presumably immutably pushing to the array), but perhaps something like this would work...

```
handleDrop: function(orderItem) {
  if (!!orderItem) {
    this.setState(
      update(this.state, { droppedItems: { $push: [orderItem] } })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, by adding components in drop signature, it works!

Comment: As you have mentioned component is working in jsx. I couldn't find what is the issue with my typescript code. If time permits please look to this code. https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/785#issuecomment-368897599